# How to delete features/records in ArcGIS Server using Python

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

How can I use python to delete records from a table, or features from a featureclass, when they are stored in ArcGIS Server?

[using REST "delete features" in arcgis api for javascript](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97920/using-rest-delete-features-in-arcgis-api-for-javascript) shows how to do this in JavaScript - what is the Python syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't find this syntax listed anywhere so I'm sharing it in case it helps someone else.

```
import urllib, urllib2, json

serviceEndPoint = "http://<server>/ArcGIS/rest/services/<name>/FeatureServer/<ID>/"

#Query the server for the objects to be deleted
params = urllib.urlencode({'where': <whereclause>, 'f': 'json', 'returnIdsOnly': 'true'})
response = urllib2.urlopen(serviceEndPoint + "query?", params).read()

#Convert the response into JSON then extract the IDs. Convert to a string
data = json.loads(response)
IDs = data["objectIds"]
range = ','.join([str(x) for x in IDs])

#Build the delete code, and submit it
delParams = urllib.urlencode({'objectIds': range, 'f': 'json'})
urllib2.urlopen(serviceEndPoint + "deleteFeatures?", delParams)
```

Comment: Is the <whereclause> the only piece of the script that I need to modify to make this work? Lets say that I need to delete all the features, can I say objectIds>0? Is there any other other part that I need to modify?

Comment: It may be better if you ask this as a new question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/76906)

Comment: @ErnestoCD yes, to do this put `OBJECTID > 0` as the `whereclause`